# body node in Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Can you please convert this cocos2d code to cocos2dx?

```
shiprightnode = [[Shipright alloc] initWithBody:shipright game:game_];
[game_ addBodyNode:shiprightnode z:1];
[shiprightnode release];
```

Comment: I think this site is for question answer, not for asking anyone for do work in your fever.Tough, tell me, do you have Shipright class? and what is the structure of that file.

Comment: @Rao27: Sorry for that.  I have difficult to change it.  Anyway, i do it for myself.  But what is the alternate word in cocos2dx for "alloc".  How will i create that any pointer reference?

Comment: replacement of alloc is create() method. So there must be create method in Shipright or in its parent class if it is inherited from other class.

Comment: yes, while converting this code to cocos2dx, you can ask question related to that.

Comment: @Rao27:  thanks.  This is i want. I am new to stack overflow. Sorry....

Comment: your welcome. U were just not active on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shiprightnode = new Shipright();
shiprightnode->init(p_game_);
game_->addBodyNode(shiprightnode);
shiprightnode->release();
```

Answer (score 0):

auto shiprightnode = Shipright::createWithGame(game_);

game_->addBodyNode(shiprightnode,1);

//no need to release shiprightnode because it create autorelease object.